# How to calculate based on the result of an aggregation?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

For example, I can get the result of the average counts of request to a specific url base on parent id with the code below:

```
client.search({
  index: 'console-*',
  body: {
    query: {
      bool: {
        query_string: {
          query: 'meta.http.url:"https://www.google.com"'
        }
      }
    },
    aggs: {
      parent_id: {
        terms: {
          field: 'parent_id'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  size: 0
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res.hits.total/res.aggregations.total.value)
})
```

Now let's say I have a number of urls like:

```
https://www.google.com
https://www.bing.com
https://www.apple.com
```

And I can use:

```
client.search({
  index: 'console-*',
  body: {
    sort: {
      '@timestamp': {
        order: 'asc'
      }
    },
    query: {
      bool: {
        must: [{
          range: {
            '@timestamp': {
              gte: 'now-5m',
              lte: 'now'
            }
          }
        }, {
          query_string: { query: '_exists_:meta.http.url' }
        }]
      }
    },
    aggs: {
      urls: {
        terms: {
          field: 'meta.http.url'
        },
        aggs: {
          total: {
            cardinality: {
              field: 'parent_id'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  size: 0
}).then(res => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
  console.log(res.aggregations.urls.buckets.map(o => {
    const res = {};
    res[o.key] = o.doc_count / o.total.value;
    return res;
  }))
})
```

Is it possible to get the result without doing any additional calculation in Node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can leverage pipeline aggregations, and more specifically, the [`bucket_script` one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html).

The `aggs` section would look like this instead and in each bucket you'll get the result of the document count divided by the total value stored in the `compute` section:

```
aggs: {
  urls: {
    terms: {
      field: 'meta.http.url'
    },
    aggs: {
      total: {
        cardinality: {
          field: 'parent_id'
        }
      },
      compute: {
        bucket_script: {
          buckets_path: {
            count: "_count",
            total: "total"
          },
          script: "params.count / params.total"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What do _count and total mean in buckets_path? Shouldn't they be "doc_count" and "total.value" instead?

Comment: Also I received error: `{"error":{"root_cause":[],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"","phase":"fetch","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[],"caused_by":{"type":"script_exception","reason":"compile error","script_stack":["count / total","^---- HERE"],"script":"count / total","lang":"painless","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Variable [count] is not defined."}}},"status":503}`

Comment: Sorry, fixed, please try again

Comment: Okay again what does _count and total mean? If I were to use this feature in other searches I'd like to know how each of these params works.

Comment: If you follow the link I gave you, you'll see how it works. `_count` refers to the number of documents in the bucket (i.e. `o.doc_count` in your code) and `total` refers to the value of the cardinality aggregation called `total` (i.e. `o.total.value`) in your code. Try it out

Comment: It works but I don't think I necessarily understood the concept. Where did you find the information that _count is equal is its parent aggregation's doc_count? It's not in this link you posted. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html

Comment: You can find if you follow the link to "buckets-path syntax" located on that page, here it is: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html#_special_paths